# "show dbs" fails on mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

This is the first time I am trying to connect to this mongo instance, which is setup by my ex-colleague. when I run "show dbs", I have seen such message:

```
rs0:SECONDARY> show dbs
2022-01-05T18:33:11.282+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1641407590, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotMasterNoSlaveOk",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1641407590, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"...="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("...")
                }
        }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs/<@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:135:19
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:87:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:906:13
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:790:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Thanks,

Jack

Following is the screenshot How I got that failure.

[image]

Comment: Did you write before that: mongod and mongo?

Comment: Hi Yarin, not sure if I understand your question. I have run "mongo -u root -p" to login, then try to check the db list, and here  I have above message.

Comment: You are connected to the secondary member of the replicaset. How do you connect?

Comment: Try the info here:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/not-master-and-slaveok-false/82369
Very likely your rep set is not initialized.

Comment: @Alex, this is a cloud project that I am working on, and underneath is of K8S, and is using both mongoDB and mysql DB. I have attached a screenshot for how I make the mongo DB connection and the error I have received.

Comment: But why you have chosen the secondary pod? Secondaries are there for failover to step up as as a primary when it goes down. By default all read/write operations are handled by primary, and in some specific usecases you can read from secondary. Now, you are connecting to a member of the replica set directly, so even if you chose primary pod you won't be able to benefit from replication. Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As you said, the secondary is read-only. And I have just located the primary one and uploading is ongoing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute:

```
   rs.slaveOk()
```

From the SECONDARY to allow show dbs after ...